# Why nothing appear though I clicked ElevatedButton in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I try to keep my code clean. But suddenly it doesn't work.
There are no errors. But although I click the `ElevatedButton`, nothing happens.

I guess there is a compatibility issue with variables in `onPressedGenerator`.

```
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:randome/HomeScreen/setting_screen.dart';
import 'package:randome/constant/color.dart';

class homescreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const homescreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<homescreen> createState() => _homescreenState();
}

class _homescreenState extends State<homescreen> {
  final rand = Random();
  Set<int> number = {};
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: PRIMARY_COLOR,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
            horizontal: 16.0,
          ),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              header(),
              middle(number: number),
              bottom(onPressed: onPressedGenerater),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
  onPressedGenerater() {
    final rand = Random();
    Set<int> number = {};
    setState(() {
      for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        number.add(rand.nextInt(1500));
        print(number) ;
      }
      if (number.length > 4 || number.length <3) {
        number.clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
          number.add(rand.nextInt(1500));
        }
      }
    });
  }
}



class header extends StatelessWidget {
  const header({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween, children: [
      Text(
        "랜덤숫자 생성기",
        style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white, fontSize: 30.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
      ),
      IconButton(
          onPressed: () async {
            final result = await Navigator.of(context)
                .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return settingscreen();
            }));
          },
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.settings,
            color: RED_COLOR,
          )),
    ]);
  }
}

class middle extends StatelessWidget {
  Set<int> number;
  middle({required this.number, Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: number
            .toList()
            .asMap()
            .entries
            .map(
              (x) => Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: x.key == 2 ? 0 : 16.0),
                child: Row(
                  children: x.value
                      .toString()
                      .split("")
                      .map(
                        (y) => Image.asset(
                          "asset/img/$y.png",
                          height: 70.0,
                          width: 50.0,
                        ),
                      )
                      .toList(),
                ),
              ),
            )
            .toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class bottom extends StatelessWidget {
  final VoidCallback onPressed;

  const bottom({required this.onPressed, Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      width: double.infinity,
      child: ElevatedButton(
          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
            primary: RED_COLOR,
          ),
          onPressed: onPressed,
          child: Text("생성하기")),
    );
  }
}
```

I tested whether it works or not.

By adding the code `print(number)` in the `onPressedGenerator` function.

See below:

[image]
It still works. So I think there is a compatibility issue with variables between `onPressedGenerator` and `class _homescreenState`.

How can I solve it?

Best people in the world please help me!

Comment: After the click event occurs what effect do you want？

Comment: The variables in `onPressedGenerator` are [shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the properties of the `_homescreenState` class.

Comment: It's hard to read code where you aren't following the capitalization convention of Dart.  Please use that.

Answer (score 0):

- The local variables should be removed and the numbers initialized

```
  onPressedGenerater() {
    number = {};
    setState(() {
      for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        number.add(rand.nextInt(1500));
        print(number);
      }
      if (number.length > 4 || number.length < 3) {
        number.clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
          number.add(rand.nextInt(1500));
        }
      }
    });
  }
```